# KDE: URLs are opened by Kate instead of the browser

Tags: kubuntu, file-association, kate

Kate is registered as default application for *.html-files.
This has the unwanted effect that html files as well as http-URLs are opened in Kate instead of Firefox.

The strange thing now is that when I move Kate down in this list and press the Apply-button, after a second or so it appears again at the top of the list.
I tried also with sudo, but it had the same effect.

I could uninstall Kate and everything went back to normal.
But as soon as I've re-installed Kate URLs are getting opened by Kate again.

How can I change the priority of the applications here?

[image]

Comment: I see something similar. Whether I move an application up or down, after pressing `Apply` the order changes!

Comment: 'The strange thing now is that when I move Kate down in this list and press the Apply-button, after a second or so it appears again at the top of the list. ' - this sounds like KDE bug 354179 - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354179 . It is marked as fixed but do you have bot the old '~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list' and the current '~/.config/mimeapps.list' ?

Comment: 'I tried also with sudo...'  Please don't use the sudo with the graphical applications. Explained at here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo

Comment: What version of the 'kde-cli-tools' are you using ?

Comment: @user26687, yes, I have both mimeapps.list files. Should I only keep `~/.config/mimeapps.list`? Re. `kde-cli-tools`, I have version 5.8.7 (according to `apt policy` from 16.04's kubuntu-ppa/backports. My system is fully updated and is a clean installation of Kubuntu 16.04 + the above backports. Of course, I've installed *some* GTK applications such as Synaptic Package Manager, Inkscape, etc.

Comment: @user26687, what do you think about `ln -s ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list ~/.config/mimeapps.list` which is found in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications because "Although deprecated, several applications still read/write to ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list. To simplify maintenance, simply symlink it ..."

Comment: As 'DK Bose' pointed there is a workaround - soft linking should keep the both  mimeapps.lists synchronized.