# In Kubuntu, how can I change the default editor for all plaintext file types from Kate to Sublime Text?

Tags: kubuntu, default-programs, text-editor

I know I can change the associated application for *individual* file types in the System Settings, but doing this for each and every file type is too much work.

Where are these associations stored? The only thing I've found mentioned is the `mimeapps.list` file, but that file seems to only contain settings for my default browser, nothing else.

Many other threads refer to a `defaults.list` file, but this file does not exist on Kubuntu.

Comment: You could mention which version of Kubuntu because the solution *maybe* dependent on that,

Comment: @DKBose 16.04.2

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/946901/kde-urls-are-opened-by-kate-instead-of-the-browser for hints.

Comment: Only tangentially relevant, it seems to me. I can change individual associations fine but I'm looking for a way to change all of them (or a lot of them) at once.

Comment: You mentioned `mimeapps.list`. Which one? The one in `~/.local/share/applications` or the one in `~/.config`? I understand that the former is supposed to be deprecated. And KDE doesn't use `defaults.list`. Apparently, [that's a GNOME thing](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2014-February/013177.html).

Comment: Both lists have the same contents, only one entry for the browser.

Comment: Please see if https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html and https://github.com/stevearc/dotfiles/blob/master/mimeapps.list can offer you some guidance.